# Enable Google Account Picker on Web

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

How can i enable Google account picker on Web like the one on this website in the top right corner:

Link - https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/boarding-pass-stamping-may-soon-be-passe/articleshow/65140775.cms

[image]

I tried to find documentation on Google but came up empty.

It's running in an iframe with src starting from: https://smartlock.google.com/iframe/request?client=https%3A%2F%2Ftimesofindia.indiatimes.com&renderMode=navPopout

What is this service called and where can i find it's documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is what you are looking for.

https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @CreatOff Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is called Google Yolo which was supposed to be a one-click sign-in/ sign-up solution. It is no longer available, most probably due to the security concerns - https://neerajsinha.com/google-one-tap-yolo/

Update Dec 23, 2020:
It looks like Google has reintroduced Google Yolo by the name of One Tap. So you can now get more information here - https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web